# Why is my method not async?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

When I have the following code, it executes async:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => new Class(string, string2, string3));
```

When I make a generic method out of it like this, async doesn´t work anymore:

```
private void StartTask<T>(string, string2, string3) where T : BaseClass10
{
    var instance = (T) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof (T), string, string2, string3);
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => instance);
}
```

I execute it like this:

```
StartNew<SomeClass>(string1, string2, string);
StartNew<SomeClass2>(string1, string2, string);
```

The second StartNew gets executed after the first finishes...what could be the reason?

Edit:
SomeClass code:

```
public class SomeClass {
public SomeClass(string1, string2, string3){
// Long running process that takes time to complete. For example Thread.Sleep or what ever.
 }  
}
```

Comment: Show the actual code that produces the output you're seeing. How do you verify that they aren't asynchronous?

Comment: Because I add Thead.Sleep in SomeClass1 and it sleeps.

Comment: I don't get it. None of your method is asynchronous. First one creates instance in `Task` second generic version does nothing with `Task` if constructor takes time to complete then it makes difference.

Comment: Task is asynchronous.

Comment: Show us your actual test code. If you're putting `Thread.Sleep` in the wrong place.. of course it will execute one after the other..

Comment: I´m adding Thread.Sleep in the constructor or anywhere. Why does it matter? It´s not async anyways. lol.

Comment: Its very important to understanding what you're seeing. The __only__ thing that is asynchronous is the closure that you've created in the `StartNew` call. Everything else is synchronous. Show your test code.. or I will vote to close the question (since it's pointless without it).

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Let's Go for it.

Comment: Edited now to include it.

Comment: As mentioned multiple times, your long running process is in the contructor.  The constructor executes before the call to Task.Factory.StartNew().  Have your task call a long running method of the class, and then see how that goes.

Comment: Why does it work when I only have "Task.Factory.StartNew(() => new Class(string, string2, string3));" ?

Comment: Because the constructor in that case is executing within the Task.Factory.StartNew.  Your StartTask() method constructs the class first, then call Task.Factory.StartNew.

Comment: Exactly as I suspected.

Comment: @Dimo Typing `Task` into your code doesn't automatically make everything surrounding it asynchronous.

Comment: I know it gets added to a queue but that doesn't have anything to do with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original `StartTask` method:

```
private void StartTask<T>(string, string2, string3) where T : BaseClass10
{
    var instance = (T) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof (T), string, string2, string3);
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => instance);
}
```

If the long running process happens in the constructor of `T`, then notice that the long running process happens outside of `Task.Factory.StartNew()`.

Move the long running process into a method (e.g `LongRunningProcess()`) on `T`, then you can do this:

```
private void StartTask<T>(string, string2, string3) where T : BaseClass10
{
    var instance = (T) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof (T), string, string2, string3);
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => instance.LongRunningProcess());
}
```

I don't think it's a good idea to have the long running process happening in a constructor.

Comment: +1. `It is really a code smell if you happen to write a long running process in the constructor`. `Object creation should be faster; doing operations with that object instance can take longer time depending upon the scenario`

Answer (score 3):

I see what you mean. Your first version calls the constructor in `Task` (probably threadpool thread). So it will return immediately before completion. where as in your second method you call `Activator.CreateInstance` which is what actually creating the instance and executing the constructor.

As you can see `Activator.CreateInstance` is called from calling thread itself rather than inside the task, it executes synchronously.

To make the generic method as you expect you need to wrap it in `Task` like this:

```
private void StartTask<T>(string, string2, string3) where T : BaseClass10
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => (T) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof (T), string, string2, string3));
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that. However the first SomeClass gets executed several times.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that comment.